# Parse a complex hash and return changes to keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

I'm using json-compare gem to compare two different json files.

Example file 1:

```
{"suggestions": [
      {
        "id1": 1,
        "title1": "Test",
        "body1": "Test"
       }
    ]
}
```

Example file 2:

```
{"suggestions": [
      {
        "id2": 1,
        "title2": "Test",
        "body2": "Test"
      }
    ]
}
```

The gem works well and spits out a hash that looks like this:

```
  {:update=> 
    {"suggestions" => 
        {:update=>
          {0=>
            {:append=>
                {"id2"=>1, "title2"=>"Test", "body2"=>"Test"}, 
             :remove=>
                {"id1"=>1, "title1"=>"Test", "body1"=>"Test"}, 
             }
          }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I parse this and return all the places where json Keys were changed? For the sake of simplicity, how would I put to the console:

```
id1 changed to id2
title1 changed to title2
body1 changed to body2
```

For the purpose of what I'm building I don't need to know changes to the values. I just need to know that id1 became id2, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by, for example, "`id2` changed to `id1`"? How do you deduce that from the hash? Do `:update`, `:append` and `:remove` have meanings that are significant to the question? (I'm not familiar with the gem.) Please edit your question to provide further explanation.

Comment: Updated the question with examples of the json files. The :append, etc is injected by the gem into the hash.

Comment: If `h` is the hash returned by the gem, `arr = h[:update]["suggestions"][:update][0]
=> {:append=>{"id2"=>1, "title2"=>"Test", "body2"=>"Test"}, :remove=>{"id1"=>1, "title1"=>"Test", "body1"=>"Test"}}`, from which you could compute `pairs = g[:append].keys.zip(arr[:remove].keys)
#=> [["id2", "id1"], ["title2", "title1"], ["body2", "body1"]]` This provides the values you need for the `puts` statements. Is this what you want? It's not general, however.

Answer (score 1):

Except if you are relaying on key ordering there is no way to tell that `id1` got replaced by `id2` and `title2` by `title1`, or that `id1` became `title1` and `id2` became `title2`. Sounds like you would need specific logic related to the actual key names (in this example searching for different integer suffixes).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be enough for the purpose:

```
def find_what_changed_in(mhash, result = [])
  result << mhash
  return if mhash.keys == [:append, :remove]
  mhash.keys.each { |k| find_what_changed_in(mhash[k], result) }
  result.last
end

find_what_changed_in(changes)

#=> {:append=>{"id2"=>1, "title2"=>"Test", "body2"=>"Test"}, :remove=>{"id1"=>1, "title1"=>"Test", "body1"=>"Test"}}
```

Where:

```
changes =   {:update=> 
    {"suggestions" => 
        {:update=>
          {0=>
            {:append=>
                {"id2"=>1, "title2"=>"Test", "body2"=>"Test"}, 
             :remove=>
                {"id1"=>1, "title1"=>"Test", "body1"=>"Test"}, 
...
```